# SQL unique sequencial id for resultset based on accounting entities

Tags: sql, sequence

I have an accounting resultset of this format:

**InvoiceNo,Date,AccountingDepartment,AmountDebit,AmountCredit,Sequence**

It contains charges and payments. It consists of "accounting entities".

An accounting entity is a set of records that contains all the charges and payments of a single invoice

I need to generate a sequencial numbering for the Sequence field - one for each entity

It can be done using cursor but I would like to learn a more elegant way

Thanx!

example

InvoiceNo,Date,AccountingDepartment,AmountDebit,AmountCredit,**Sequence**

1300,2012-02-01,AA,25,NULL,**1**

1300,2012-02-01,BB,45,NULL,**1**

1300,2012-02-01,NULL,65,**1**

1301,2012-02-01,AA,10,NULL,**2**

1301,2012-02-01,NULL,NULL,10,**2**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  *,
  DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY InvoiceNo) AS sequence
FROM
  yourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have MSSQL you can use *ROW_NUMBER* function

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY InvoiceNo) AS Sequence
FROM [Table]
```

Comment: Thanx a lot Dis but your code generates sequence numbers for every row. I want sequence number for each entity, not each row.

Comment: can you explain with more details?
Is entity identifier InvoiceNo?
and do you need?
InvoiceNo - Sequence | a - 1 | a - 1 | b - 2 | c - 3 | c - 3 | c - 3

Comment: Dis, I have edited my post and posted an example. I hope it helps :)

Comment: See answer by Dems:)

 DENSE_RANK()